# Specify nested fields Django

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I was looking into Django Rest Framework Documentation and I read about Nested Serialization, and how Depth could be used, there it specify the depth of relationships:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['id', 'account_name', 'users', 'created']
        depth = 1
```

But doing in this way, all fields get the depth of 1, how can I specify which field I want to be nested, like, for account_name, use a depth = 1, and for user a depth = 2

Comment: Define a serializer class for your *related field* and wire-up

Comment: write a recursive serializer class and apply it to your related field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you give a code example?